# Completion callback using closures in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

When I just going through with a library, there is an Internal property in a Singelton class. like this :-

```
class CameraHandler: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

      static let shared = CameraHandler()

     //MARK: Internal Properties
     var imagePickedBlock: ((UIImage) -> Void)?   ///// What kind of property is THIS ???

     func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
       if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
           self.imagePickedBlock?(image)
       } else{
           print("Something went wrong")
       }
     }

 }
```

As you can see above `imagePickedBlock` variable changes when user selects an image. And also below function will fire. So my question is what type of Property is this? Thanks

```
CameraHandler.shared.imagePickedBlock = { (image) in
     /* get your image here */
     print("Got image!!!!")
}
```

Comment: That's a closure. In Objective-C, it's called a block.

Comment: `var imagePickedBlock: ((UIImage) -> Void)?`  stored Property  of type closure with nill value so you needn't any initalizer for `CameraHandler `

Comment: You may refer to Swift document. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: Thanks @Leo and@Larme :)

Comment: That is string reference of closure as @Larme said. it will be executed whenever it will be triggered generally it is used for async task handling